# ELMAH - MVC 3 - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have installed [Elmah for MVC](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc) using NuGet, I'am able to login with success error in the db.
The only problem is that I cannot access the `/elmah` URL to access the Error Log Page.

Here part of my configuration, could you please point out if I have any misconfiguration?

Thanks

ERROR

> *403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.*

In my `web.config`:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Administrator" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
  </appSettings>
```

In `global.asax`:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Comment: How are you handling authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(This is all from the documentation/getting started)

You don't need the following line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
```

The next line takes care of it.

Everything you need to configure is in your `web.config` file.  Something like:

```
<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="mySqlConnString" />
</elmah>
<location path="elmah.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using MVC are you sure I should use <location path="elmah.axd">? Thanks

Comment: It's VERY possible that Emlah has been updated and i'm using an older config.  I think the important part is the `allowRemoteAccess` and making sure you are authenticated as jrummell noted.

Comment: For MVC you'll use appSettings with entries like <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />. Install this NuGet and it'll modify your config appropriately: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC

Comment: He said Elmah MVC. The settings you showed are not for MVC, they are for the earlier version of elmah. The allow remote access string however is required

Comment: I only needed this line  <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" /> thanks

Comment: Saved the day for me as well :) However, in my case it's <security allowRemoteAccess="1" /> I'm using elmah 1.2.13605.0

Answer (score 34):

Just in case anyone comes across the same issue I had.

This was my code, which is wrong:

```
<elmah>
    <security allowremoteAccess="true" />
</elmah>
```

The issue was the **r** in allow**r**emoteAccess, it was in lower case, when it should have been upper-case!

Correct code:

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
</elmah>
```

Comment: Great help, I solve my problem with <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />, thx.

Comment: Good answer!    While Elmah.MVC adds most of the necessary configuration to web.config, this line is missing.

Comment: Lowercase "r" victim here, have my thanks and my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I had added the remote access to my web.config:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="adminrole" />  

<elmah>
      <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
      <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </elmah>
```

I had to edit Elmah.Athz.config on the server and add the role I wanted to give access to elmah. I had to add `^adminrole`

Comment: Jeez, saved me man, totally missed out this file. That's it. Thank you.